# Cake 1.2 Currency Method into GBP £

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

How do I use the currency method to format my numbers into GBP (£) ?

The following code in returning $110.00, I want it to return £110.00 please

```
 <div id="subtotal"> <?php echo $number->currency($invoice['Invoice']['subTotal']); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $number->currency($invoice['Invoice']['subTotal'], 'GBP');`

Check out the api docs: http://api12.cakephp.org/class/number-helper#method-NumberHelpercurrency